# what is core:schema:warn Unknown property A for component/system B in Aframe?

Tags: aframe

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is this warn???

My project works fine, but these errors are annoying

Hundreds of such warnings occur. I want to remove these

i don`t use Vue, React, etc..

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the property is not defined in the schema for those components.

In your case `x`, `y` are not defined properties for the `spot` component. `src`, `pop`, `name`, `type`, `count` are not defined for the `detail` component. Look for places in your code where those are set (like your HTML) and adjust.

Comment: thank you!! I found out I had to define the schema in AFRAME.registerComponent() in JS!!

Comment: Glad it's working. Flagging the answer as correct will be greatly appreciated.